# Generate highlighted and summarized search preview using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a function that yields highlighted and summarized preview of the given text. Please see the following code snippet.

```html
<div>
Search: 
<input value='vestibulum' disabled/>
</div>

<div style='margin-top: 20px'>Output I want:</div>
<div style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px'>
...diam lectus <mark>vestibulum</mark> risus, eu <mark>vestibulum</mark> turpis quam in lorem. Vivamus posuere nibh leo, sit amet pharetra velit convallis sed. Sed porta convallis justo ac auctor. <mark>Vestibulum</mark> ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus...
</div>

<div style='margin-top: 20px'>Original Text:</div>
<div style='border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px'>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lacus tempus, pharetra dui vel, egestas massa. Integer metus enim, varius sed quam sed, convallis volutpat lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam efficitur, tortor quis sagittis sollicitudin, diam lectus vestibulum risus, eu vestibulum turpis quam in lorem. Vivamus posuere nibh leo, sit amet pharetra velit convallis sed. Sed porta convallis justo ac auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nulla et luctus leo, eu dignissim nunc. Phasellus vel fringilla sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean et dui ut ipsum pretium ullamcorper. Aenean hendrerit dolor et lorem auctor ullamcorper.
</p>
<p>
Donec aliquet, purus ut tempor efficitur, velit eros luctus turpis, in pretium elit augue vel eros. Morbi eget dui ullamcorper, semper magna sit amet, cursus nulla. Aenean augue dolor, varius eu orci a, efficitur auctor diam. Quisque tempor lacus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec imperdiet pellentesque nunc, sed accumsan sem lacinia sed. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam placerat odio et leo ultricies ultrices. Cras nulla lacus, maximus in risus ut, auctor auctor vestibulum.
</p>
</div>
```

The function I want to implement should look like this:

```
const getSummarizedPreview = (query, text, windowSize) => {
    // query: The word that should be highlighted. It's just one word, not a phrase.
    // text: Original Text.
    // windowSize: The maximum length of text returned.
}
```

Note that the last word of the text is also `vestibulum`, but `getSummarizedPreview` smartly chose more **relevant** part of the text based on the frequency of the `query`.

I think this might be pretty complicated to implement, so any advice, pseudocode, or introduction to library that does the simliar thing would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use full text search of `Elasticsearch`. See quick intro [here](https://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-full-text-search-rest-api).

OR you can implement this feature by yourself:

- Look in your `original text` i see it have multi paragraph (

  tag). You can split it into an array, then loop all of this array elements.
- In the loop, using regex like below to find count frequency of appearance of query word:

```
var temp = "This is a string.";
var count = (temp.match(/is/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

- Get element have max count.
- Replace query word with highlighted query word, like: `vestibulum` with `<mark>vestibulum</mark>`
- Return formatted string for display highlighted matched query word.

This is an interesting question and I am also looking for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not considering adopting elasticsearch for such a small project. I'll try implementing with your 2nd solution first. Please let me know once you find a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I am also looking for a better solution.